# Weight painting not applied for particular vertices

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I'm weight painting my character and some of the vertices on the finger are not moving with the others despite the fact that it is included in painted area.

Here's the example of moving the finger's bone and it's top view with vertices selected.
[image]

Maybe you've got some ideas of fixing that.

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: My project exceeds maximum size (24Mb) so I've uploaded it to Google drive. Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16-3hkaFURk2YY-zkh4kOq5GSEI3Q1XHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The bone's name is index1.L but actually bone named spine2 gives the same problem and I cannot understand why. As for spine2 when rotate it along the X axis so the character leans left and right several vertices  on the neck are staying on the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I enable the modifier's *On Cage* option, select the vertex, open the N panel and take a look at the *Vertex Weights*, I can see that this vertex is also part of the group called *Spine2*. Just remove it from this group (press the X button):

[image]

Parenting *With Automatic Weights* won't always work fine, you often need to give it correction in *Weight Paint* mode. Select the armature, shift select the object, switch it to *Weight Paint* mode, select a bone with Ctrl left click. In the brush settings, don't forget to disable *Front Faces OnlY* if you want to paint through:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Finger issue is actually solved. What do you think is the reason for these artifacts? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZzYPFm-VZpf2a7vrmqRMXuBavlgehHSZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: same thing, it's a bad parentage issue, but it's hard to tell how it happened, as I said if it's caused by the Spine2 bone bad parenting, then try to reparent for this bone only for the moment?

Comment: Spine2 has spine1 as a parent. Which other bone  should I assign it as a parent? 
I used empty groups for all the bones not automatic

Comment: reparenting With Automatic Weights doesn't seem to fix the issue, you should try to correct that in Weight Paint mode. In the brush settings, disable Front Faces Only

Comment: That's exactly  how I'm trying to fix this issue with Weight paint mode but I don't see any vertices not included in any of the bones. Why can this happen?

Comment: Wow I see your gif erasing these vertices, how do you erase them? Which keys?

Comment: a vertex can be wrongly assigned to a vertex group or non-assigned to the good one, you often need to give some corrections, see my edit

Comment: Yep that worked! Thank you so much for your help!